# datetimepicker update mindate maxdate

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I am using jquery datetimepicker for two textboxes From date To date. I want to update the values mindate and maxdate from the other text box. The first time it is working fine but if I change the values on debug are correct but the datetimepicker doesnt update. My question is how I will make datetimepicker to update. Reading the code I think it is more clear. Thank you

```
    $(".DatePickerFieldOnHire").live('click', function () {

        var defaultDateTime = "";
        var dateFrom = "";
        var dateTo = "";
        dateFrom = document.getElementById('WebReportForm1_Value_DeliveryDate').value;
        dateTo = document.getElementById('WebReportForm1_Value_ExpectedRedeliveryDate').value;
        var now = new Date();
        var dateNow=now.format("dd-mm-yy HH:mm z");

dateFrom = document.getElementById('WebReportForm1_Value_DeliveryDate').value;
            dateTo = document.getElementById('WebReportForm1_Value_ExpectedRedeliveryDate').value;
            var now = new Date();
            var dateNow=now.format("dd-mm-yy HH:mm z");

            if (dateFrom == null) {
                dateFrom = new Date(1999, 10 - 1, 25);
            }
            if (dateTo == null) {
                dateTo = new Date(2055, 10 - 1, 25);
                defaultDateTime = dateNow;
            } else {
                if (dateTo > dateNow) {
                    defaultDateTime = dateNow;
                }
                else {
                    defaultDateTime = dateTo;
                }
            }          
            var inputOff = "";
            inputOff = $('[id*="OffHireDateField"]').val();
            if (inputOff != "") {
               dateFrom = inputOff;
            }

            $(this).datetimepicker({
             showOn: 'focus', showTimezone: false, ampm: true, dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                timeFormat: "HH:mm z",
                minDate: dateFrom,
                maxDate: dateTo,
                showTimezone: true,
                defaultDate: defaultDateTime,
                onSelect: function () { }
            }).focus();

        });
```

and the From textbox

```
 $(".DatePickerFieldOffHire").live('click', function () {

        var dateFrom = "";
        var dateTo = "";
        dateFrom = document.getElementById('WebReportForm1_Value_DeliveryDate').value;
        dateTo = document.getElementById('WebReportForm1_Value_ExpectedRedeliveryDate').value;


        if (dateFrom == null) {
            dateFrom = new Date(1999, 10 - 1, 25);
        }

        if (dateTo == null) {
            dateTo = new Date(2055, 10 - 1, 25);
            defaultDateTime = dateNow;
        } else {
            if (dateTo > dateNow) {
                defaultDateTime = dateNow;
            }
            else {
                defaultDateTime = dateTo;
            }
        }

        var inputOn = "";
        inputOn = $('[id*="OnHireDateField"]').val();
        if (inputOn != "") {
            dateTo = inputOn;
        }

        $(this).datetimepicker({
            showOn: 'focus', showTimezone: false, ampm: true, dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            timeFormat: "HH:mm z",
            minDate: dateFrom,
            maxDate: dateTo,
            showTimezone: true,
            defaultDate: defaultDateTime,
            onSelect: function () { }
        }).focus();

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, I did not check the code thoroughly as you have not included a JSFiddle, but from what I can see, it looks like the first time, `dateFrom` and `dateTo` are `Date` objects but from the second time on they are `Strings`.

This might be an issue.

Your date format `dd-mm-yy` does not comply with the [default format](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) `yy-mm-dd`.

Comment: Thank you for the comments I changed it but the issue is still there. The datetimepicker doesn't update the mindate and maxdate values after the first time that are set

Comment: Did you down grade my questiong because I didn't include JSFiddle @StrubT